# Hodoop + Nutch 1.15 + Solr Cloud 7.3.1 index no result

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, nutch, solrcloud

Him I have a Cluster based on Hadoop. I use Nutch 1.15 with success and i crawl some urls. 
I have installed Solr 7.3.1 and I like to use the Cloud one, So When i run SOlr with this cmd:

```
./solr-7.3.1/bin/solr start -c
```

I have also setup in nutch-site.xml some solr vars:

```
<property>                                                                                                 
   <name>solr.server.type</name>                                                                           
   <value>cloud</value>                                                                                    
</property>                                                                                                

<property>
   <name>solr.server.url</name>                                                                       
   <value>http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch_collection/</value>                                       
</property>

<property>
   <name>solr.zookeeper.url</name>                                                        
   <value>http://localhost:9983/</value>                                                                 
</property>
```

and this for index to solr:

```
 bash ./run_nutch.sh solrindex -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch_collection/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

No errors and job finish, but no documents on my collection...

What i miss?
Thanks

Comment: In nutch 1.15 you must configure conf/index-writers.xml with your collection URL

Answer (score 0):

solr.server.url is now removed from nutch 1.15 version. You now have to configure a single XML file ***(conf/index-writers.xml)***

The default value setup in index-writers.xml is `http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch/`. So either you want to change that value in the xml file or create core named `nutch` instead of n`utch_collection` and test it out.

> https://apache.org/dist/nutch/1.15/CHANGES.txt